# Git "leaky" branches?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-merge

We usually do feature development on new branches and then bugfixes on the master branch. This time, for some reason, one of the feature branches had a leak where it was merged back into master when it shouldn't have.

From the screenshot, you can see that we have the feature branches sms_open and 121217. 121217 was supposed to be merged into master after our sprint and then the sms_open branch had a longer time estimate so it needed to be pushed back in a future release. I cannot figure out why sms_open commit 609129d was merged back in. I see the unwanted merge happening at 75e845b, but the developer who did this denies that sms_open was being merged back. Is there a way to verify this in any way?

FYI, the git tool used here is SourceTree for Mac OS.

[image: source tree screenshot]

Comment: The git version on the server is 1.7.4.1. Each developer may have a different version. Not sure if that could be an issue here.

Answer (score 6):

When you trace the greenish line down starting from `121217`, you can see that it is connected to `sms_open`. This means that the history of `121217` is based on `sms_open` (it is one of its parent commits).

So whoever started the `121217` branch based it on `sms_open` instead of `master` (probably by mistake). This could be the author of commit `e70759c`.

When merging a branch in Git, all commits from the branch to merge that are not yet part of the branch that is being merged into will be part of the result. That's why the commits of `sms_open` were also merged.

Comment: is there a way to see which branch was created first and which it was based on? from the graph, it's still a bit fuzzy. how can i do such a verification from command line? the main git repository is on a centos machine.

Comment: You can examine the history to answer that. To see what other branches are fully contained in `121217`, you can use `git log --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit 121217`. To see which commits you will be merging (e.g. into `master`), you can use `git log master..121217`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how to read the graph generated by the first command you suggested. How do I differentiate other branches? I'm assuming the results shown are all part of 121217?

Answer (score 0):

There is something fishy in that screenshot. A message like "Merge branch 'xxx'" is the default message when merging into **master**.

There is commit c8cb6 which implies that the blue line is master.
But then there is 75e8 which implies that the yellow line is master.
Unfortunately the other messages are anonymized and therefore not helpful in understanding what is going on. It is especially important which commit is from which developer. - Seems to me like someone worked on master and renamed that branch later. (But I have not enough details to tell.)

If the history does not make sense there might be a fast-forward-merge involved or a forced push, especially a ff-merge is mean as it is simply not recorded in the history.

If you have access to your official git repository, the reflogs there, might give you a hint who pushed what and when.